# How do I uninstall Rust on Fedora 26?

Tags: rust, uninstallation

I installed Rust on my machine via `dnf` following [these instructions](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/rust/rust-installation.html). Now I want to install Rustup, but it's unable to be installed alongside another Rust installation.
So, how do I uninstall the Rust compiler so I can install Rustup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `dnf history` and find the transaction which installed Rust. Use `dnf history undo NNN` to undo this transaction.  This will uninstall all dependencies which were installed along with Rust.  You may have to do the same thing for Cargo if you installed it separately.